# Cycle Through Multiple Body Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm new to development so please go easy on me. Everything I code is from scratch and my own.

I've began creating a body background image slider for one single page of my eCommerce platform and I'm a bit stuck on where to go next with it.

Please see here:

https://zoeyplayground-com.zoeysite.com/lookbook

Currently it is able to fade the body background when clicking the next and previous buttons, but I can't work out a way that this can be converted to handle more than one image per button. I will need the slider to be able to cycle through multiple body background images.

Please see the code below:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Remove header from lookbook page and add background1 -->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (top.location.pathname === '/lookbook')
{
    jQuery("body").addClass("background1");
    jQuery("#root-header-cp-41e961ff2cbb3d4e6ae72927272f2db5").addClass("removeheader");
}
});
</script>

<!-- Toggle background2 when 'next' is clicked -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".next").click(function() {
            jQuery("body").removeClass("background1");
            jQuery("body").addClass("background2");
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Toggle background1 when 'back' is clicked -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".back").click(function() {
            jQuery("body").removeClass("background2");
            jQuery("body").addClass("background1");
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Container and images -->

<div id="toggle" width="100%">
<img src="/media/import/back.png" class="back">
<img src="/media/import/next.png" class="next">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Min-height due to hard-coded height issue */

.root-body {
    min-height: 0 !important;
}

/* Transition for background image changes */

body {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out !important;
}

/* Hide footer on all pages */

.root-footer {
    display: none;
}

/* Removeheader class for the lookbook page */

.removeheader {
    display: none;
}

/* Body background options */

.background1 { 
    background: url('/media/import/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background2 {
    background: url('/media/import/background2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Toggle Buttons */

#toggle .next {
    float: right;
}

#toggle img {
    margin-top: 400px;
    display: inline;
}

#toggle img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Any advice or guidance on what I should do next is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1; // current background index
    var max_backgrounds = 2; // number of backgrounds it will work with any number
    jQuery(".next").click(function() {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("background" + current);
        // next background index or first one if it's the last one
        current++;
        if (current > max_backgrounds) {
            current = 1;
        }
        // change background to background1, background2 ...
        jQuery("body").addClass("background" + current);
    });
    jQuery(".back").click(function() {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("background" + current);
        // previous background index or last one if current is the first one
        current--;
        if (current < 1) {
            current = max_backgrounds
        }
        // change background to background1, background2 ...
        jQuery("body").addClass("background" + current);
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe add some comments to help matt's understanding?

Comment: Hi jcubic. Do I replace this with my current jQuery for adding and removing the classes? Do I need to change the "background" to the relevant background classes such as "background1" and "background2"? Thank you

Comment: @matt136 no you don't the backgorund will be background1 or background2 because of index added at the end.

Comment: Hey. This looks to work great, thank you so much. Do you know if it's possible for me to add a quick crossfade to this or have I restricted myself with the use of addClass? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't have effects with background image and classes, but you can ask antother question how to create this type of effect.